# How to create a shrinked image of my working Rpi SD card

Tags: image, backup

So i have this SD card of 64 GB lying around here. I want to distribute this image to other people which might have 8GB SD cards.

I've tried the following:

- Read the image with win32 disk imager, copy to VM in ubuntu and try to resize using this script http://sirlagz.net/2013/03/10/script-automatic-rpi-image-downsizer/.
- No luck because i keep getting the error "Bad superblock" and no blocks mentioned in the list are helping me to solve the problem.
- I've tried to manully shrink the partions with gparted, but gparted gives me the exact same problem (bad superblock) and thus I can't resize because gparted won't let me.
- Ive tried creating an image directly from my ubuntu VM but the same problem occured.

Can anyone help me? I'm getting really frustrated here ...

Comment: A bad superblock usually indicates corruption of the card, and should not be used to create images from. I would suggest recreating the image (preferably on a new card) and trying again.

Comment: But i can boot fine on the SD card, can't this be an issue with the creation of the .img?

Comment: it is possible, but either way you will be shrinking/reproducing a card that has a problem and may propagate that error to the copies. Just because the card/Pi are working does not mean that they will continue to work correctly. A superblock is one of the mechanisms used to prevent data loss and corruption so you never know when it will come back to bite you in the butt.

Comment: I repeated the proces of putting Raspbian on my SD card, seting up my project but still the same problem occured. It seems like there is something going on once I read from the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

I'd give gparted a try in your linux VM. That way, you can try one operation at a time and get feedback rather than just running a cut & paste script.

Depending on what you've customized, you can speed things up by for a rebuild recording what packages you've installed on the source (64GB) card by doing "dpkg --get-selections" and saving the installed package list off. On a newly minted card, you can do "dpkg --get-selections" to read them in, then "apt-get dselect-upgrade" to install them. A few backups of stuff you customized, and the process should go pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments said, you need a clean install to correct that. You could copy the files to a clean fs but that would be inadvisable.

Comment: This did not fix it, I tried again and I got the same result with another SD card. The image itself written onto a SD card does not even report a bad superblock.